# Is there a trigger object I can write to ensure a foreign key, which was left nullable when it was written, is filled in?

Tags: database, triggers

I have a database orders table with a foreign key that refers to a customer id in another table. the customer and orders table is a one-to-many relationship. There are several orders in the orders table that do not have a customer id (the foreign key) included in the orders table because the foreign key column was left nullable:

```
create table orders1 
(
orderID int,
customerID int,
customerLName varchar(50),
customerFName varchar(50),
orderTotal float,
 primary key (orderID),
 foreign key (customerID) references customer1(customerID)   -- left nullable
 );
```

I can't go back an fix the entries that have no customer IDs attached, but is there a trigger object I can create that will alert the user if they do not fill in the customer ID value in the future?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no trigger/code you can write that will be able to guess what customer id a random order should belong to if the insert omits the customer id.

Your best move is to fix the rows that have null customer id and make the FK not nullable.

One reasonable way to fix the rows is to create a dummy customer record and associate the orphaned orders to it. Once that is done, and you alter the column to not null, you will have stopped the rot and can sift through the data to try to figure out what customer those orders actually belong to. You might find the answer in application logs, or perhaps other entities such as payment etc, or maybe the orders are so old nobody cares.